# Is there any way I can create a reusable logging project for use in web-applications?

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I was wondering if I can create a *project* in eclipse or for the matter any Java IDE in which I can write my log4j initialization code and save it as a project so I can just import it in any workspace. I know how to configure a servlet in which I initialize the logger in the `init()` method and load the servlet on startup but that requires an entry in the `web-xml` which changes depending on the application.

Is there any way I can create a **resuable** project where there is no requirement for dependency on the DD ?

Comment: What exact steps do you need to have in a standard location?

Comment: @Stephen - Deployment Descriptor* :)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - What I mean to say is what **type** should I select when creating a _new project_ in eclipse and how should I go about writing the code?

Comment: Most people would say "the web.xml file" .... if they wanted other programmers to understand them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @Stephen C's answer, some application servers already come with a predefined logging congfiguration. If you're using JBoss, it already has its own `log4j` configuration in a file called `jboss-log4j.xml`, which defines a standard configuration, which you can adapt to your needs.

Other than that, I recommend to bundle a configuration with your application like described in the other answer.

Even smarter and more flexible is to use a log wrapper in your application, which will abstract from the underlying logging framework. Take a look at these:

- SLF4J (preferred): http://www.slf4j.org/
- Commons Logging: http://commons.apache.org/logging/

If you use one of these, you can then configure them to use the logging framework of the server you're deploying to. Many of the popular open-source frameworks use these log wrapper frameworks for similar reasons. Take a look at them, then adopt one as your standard - I strongly recommend SLF4J.

Answer (score 3):

> I know how to configure a servlet in which I initialize the logger in the init() method and load the servlet on startup ...

There is probably a better way.

For instance, the way I do log4j configuration on a servlet (using Tomcat) is to simply put the "log4j.properties" file on the classpath; e.g. in ".../webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/classes/".  Log4j's default strategy for locating the logging properties will find it there ... with no need for you to write any Java code.

Configuring the logging system from Java code is (IMO) a bad idea because it means that you have to change, rebuild and redeploy Java code in order to tweak the logging.

Comment: So you do you mean that I just create the `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` file, configure it the way I want and just add it to my classpath?

Comment: Yes.  Though, to pedantic I specifically mean the webapp's classpath when it is deployed in the web container.  [[ If "you" had a classpath, people would notice your eyes glazing over every few minutes as your brain garbage collected :-) ]]

Answer (score 2):

One of the major problems with using a logging framework *inside* your web application is that you usually end up with wanting to write to a file, and this is not allowed within the servlet API, causing you to become subtly vendor dependent and not work well with multi-computer deployments.

I would strongly suggest that you consider converting your code to use [SLJF4](http://slf4j.org/) for your actual logging statements as it allows you to

- become back end independent.
- Use the "{}" placeholders to write simply `log.debug("a={}, b={}", a, b)` and avoid the possibly expensive generation of the actual logging string if the debug logs were not enabled without having to add a guarding `if log.debugging-enabled` statement.

These two along was reason enough for me to switch.

A very interesting way to handle logging then is to use the java.util.logging bridge to send all log statements to the Java log system which most web containers handle.  Then the web container does all the work for you, and you can use the vendors tooling for investigating log files.   Very useful!